# Do any filesystems support multiple forks / streams on directories?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, hfs+, alternate-data-stream

Apple's HFS+ supports multiple *forks* such as the old data and resource forks. NTFS supports *alternate data streams*. I believe some *nix filesystems also have some support for multiple file forks or streams.

Given that directories (folders) are just a kind of file at the filesystem level, I'm wondering if any of the filesystems which support this feature support it for dirs as well as files? (Or indeed directories in the alternate forks / streams?)

I'm mostly asking out of curiosity rather than wanting to use such a feature. But one use it would have would be additional metadata for directories, which seems to be the most common use for these streams for files currently.

Comment: NTFS supports Alternate Data Streams on directories. I don't know about the various Linux filesystems, though.

Comment: @Amazed: If you could provide a reference in an answer I would accept it.

Comment: I don't have one handy, sorry.

Comment: @Amazed: Well I eventually found this stated in a couple more places too, just none of them very official looking to link to from here ...

Comment: It should be noted that Microsoft apparently broke ADS on directories starting with Windows 8 as now copying a folder with ADS streams will not carry over the additional streams.

Answer (score 2):

The ext2, ext3, ext4, JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Btrfs and OCFS2 1.6 filesystems support [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux) for a limited amount of metadata

In order to use them, the filesystems need to have xattrs enabled, for example:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mountpoint -o user_xattr
```

Then you can set attributes:

```
setfattr -n "nameofmetadata" -v "valueofmetadata" /mountpoint/myfile
```

And get attributes:

```
getfattr /mountpoint/myfile
```